# Improving ExtraTree Regression Model Performance

Tags: regression, hyperparameters

I want to build a regression model for the data set I have given below. I have tried many things to eliminate the effects of outliers in the data set on the performance of the model, but I have not been successful. When I increase the parameter range of the model, it becomes overfit. What can I do to build a successful model?

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ramazanunlu/RegressionModel/main/final_data_Jinit%20-%20Kopya.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(url,sep=";")

MMR=df[['C3','C4', 'C5', 'C6']]
MP=df[['C7', 'C8']]
OMP=df[['C9', 'C10']]
DIF=df[['Age (years)', 'C1', 'C2', 'Male', 'Female','Target']]

MAE=[]
MSE=[]
RMSE=[]
 
results=pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(MMR.columns)):
    data=pd.concat([MMR[MMR.columns[i]],MP,OMP,DIF],axis=1)
    data.head()
    
    #X=data.drop([' Kinit'],axis=1)
    X=data.drop(['Target'],axis=1)
    y=data['Target']

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=0)
    columns=X_train.columns
    
    sc = StandardScaler()
    X_train[X.columns[0:8]] = sc.fit_transform(X_train[X.columns[0:8]])
    X_test[X.columns[0:8]] = sc.transform (X_test[X.columns[0:8]])
 
    n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 100, stop = 600, num = 6)]
    criterion=["squared_error", "absolute_error", "friedman_mse", "poisson"]
    min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10,12]
    min_samples_leaf = [2,4,6,12]
    max_depth = [5,10,15,20]
    max_features = ['sqrt','log2']

    random_grid = {
                   'n_estimators': n_estimators,
                  'criterion':criterion,
                   'max_features': max_features,
                   'max_depth': max_depth,
                   'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
                   'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf}

    rf = ExtraTreesRegressor()
    rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_distributions = random_grid,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', n_iter = 50, cv = 5, verbose=1, random_state=42, refit=True)
    
    rf_random.fit(X_train,y_train)
      
    predictions=rf_random.predict(X_test)
    
    #predictions = boxcox_transformer_target.inverse_transform(predictions1.reshape(-1, 1))
    
    MAE.append(metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, predictions))
    MSE.append(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, predictions))
    RMSE.append(np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, predictions)))
    
    
    results=pd.concat([results,pd.DataFrame(predictions)],axis=1,ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

To build your regression model I recommend you the following:

1. **Tree models already include feature selection due to its working principles in the splits, so there is no need to perform feature selection explicitly.**
2. **I recommend you Random Forest model instead of Extra Tree as your dataset size is not "big data".** Extra Trees are intended to save processing time by randomizing splits during the fitting process at the cost of introducing more variance in the errors.
3. Perform standardization to avoid scaling issues.
4. **You should always check that your model's residual are normally distributed. The regression hypothesis states that errors are random**. If you find patterns in the errors, then there are hidden features.
5. **Choose your hyper-parameters based on grid search to ensure they optimize the cost function.**

Try this code on your data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import seaborn as sns

# Assuming df is your DataFrame and 'Target' is the target column
target_column = 'Target'

# Extract features and target
X = df[['C3', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'Age (years)', 'C1', 'C2', 'Male', 'Female']]
y = df[target_column]

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Standardize the features using StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

# Create a Random Forest Regression model
rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)

# Train the model
rf_model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

# Make predictions on the test set
y_pred = rf_model.predict(X_test_scaled)

# Compute R2 score
r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(f'R2 Score: {r2}')

# Error Analysis: Compute residuals
residuals = y_test - y_pred

# Plot residuals vs. predicted values
plt.scatter(y_pred, residuals)
plt.title('Residuals vs. Predicted Values')
plt.xlabel('Predicted Values')
plt.ylabel('Residuals')
plt.show()

# Plot residuals distribution
plt.hist(residuals, bins=7)
plt.title('Distribution of Residuals')
plt.xlabel('Residuals')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()

# Perform a normality test on residuals
statistic, p_value = stats.normaltest(residuals)
print(f'Normality Test p-value: {p_value}')

# Q-Q Plot
stats.probplot(residuals, dist="norm", plot=plt)
plt.title('Q-Q Plot of Residuals')
plt.show()

# Plot feature importances
feature_importances = rf_model.feature_importances_
sorted_idx = feature_importances.argsort()[::-1]

plt.bar(range(len(feature_importances)), feature_importances[sorted_idx])
plt.xticks(range(len(feature_importances)), X.columns[sorted_idx], rotation=45)
plt.xlabel('Feature')
plt.ylabel('Feature Importance')
plt.title('Random Forest Regression - Feature Importances')
plt.show()
```

You should see something like this:

[image]

The residuals are normal so regression hypothesis hold. The R2 is poor (64%), it seems that you need more features to decrease prediction error.

The model seems correct but there are more underlying phenomena not modeled yet.

EDIT:

The sex feature seems not relevant.

**Sometimes, is not about your model, is about your data.** It seems like the data misses features to decrease the errors or simply is not enough to find the underlying pattern.

Comment: Aappreciated for your answer. I will follow your suggestions.